# Prove that if $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of natural numbers such that $\{ a_n^{-1}\}$ is an arithmetic sequence then all $a_i$ are equal

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of natural numbers such that $\left\{\frac{1}{a_n}\right\}$ is an arithmetic sequence then all the $a_n$s are equal.

I have no clue where to begin from, actually, the question is not even completely clear to me.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the hypothesis there is $r$ such that

$$\frac1{a_n}=\frac1{a_0}+nr=c+nr\implies a_n=(c+nr)^{-1}\in \Bbb N,\; \forall n\iff r=0$$
so 
$$a_n=c^{-1}=a_0,\;\forall n$$

Comment: I couldn't understand after the first comma. Would you please explain it a little more.

Comment: By the hypothesis $a_n$ is a natural number for all $n$ and we proved that 
$$a_n=\frac1{c+nr}$$
so what we can conclude?

Comment: I am clueless, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: It means $c+nr\mid 1$ and $c+nr<1$

Comment: So, since $n$ assumes integer values, $c+nr>1$, hence only possibility is $r=0$, and we get $a_n=c^{-1}=a_0$, a contradiction unless the AP sequence has 0 common difference.

Comment: Your proof is correct!

Comment: Yours...thanks for helping!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I think it would help everyone to explain what an "arithmetic sequence" is.